# Finding files without numbers in the name

Tags: bash

How can I find the files that have no numbers in the filename?

```
find ~ -name '[a-z].*'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` means not, so you can also do:

```
find ~ ! -name '*[0-9]*'
```

---

Or, more accurately,

```
find ~ -type f ! -name '*[0-9]*'
```

- `find` in home directory (`~`) files (`-type f`) 
   that does not (`!`) have numbers in name (`-name '*[0-9]*`)

---

Edit: If you want to find files without numbers and ends with i.e. *txt, 
 then do `find ~ -type f ! -name '*[0-9]*' -name '*txt'`

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
find   ~   -not -name '*[0-9]*'
```

Comment: How can I search on a specific extension? Like this: find ~ -not -name '*[0-9]*.txt'

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that you want all `.txt` files that don't contain numbers in their names? Are you saying that you want all files, except for `.txt` with numbers in their names? Something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, i want all .txt files that don't contain numbers in their names.